# String arguments break optional argument default values?

Tags: functions, optional-arguments, parameters

Following a tip in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31759/guidelines-on-giving-readable-names-to-variables) post, I use string parameters to label my functions. For example, instead of `f[x]:=x^2`, I use `f["label",x_]:=x^2`.

Unfortunately, this strategy breaks the default values for optional arguments, at least when the default value is a global variable.

What should happen:

`f[x_,y_:var]:=x+y
var=10;
f[1]
11
var=20;
f[1]
21`

What happens when using string parameters as a label:

`g["label",x_,y_:var]:=x+y
var=10;
g["label",1]
11
var=20;
g["label",1]
11`

It doesn't update to the new value when the global variable is changed. Why not? And more importantly, how can I fix this (without changing my nice labeling scheme, I hope)?

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way, with or without your "label" construct. Hint: Look carefully at what you're doing and the state of `var` and `g` as you're doing it, it will be obvious why the example shown exhibits the behavior you observe, and why that behavior is expected and unrelated to your "label" construct.

Comment: Try `ClearAll[var]; g["label",x_,y_:var]:=x+y;`.  (I'd recommend `ClearAll[g, var]`.)

Comment: But I want to be able to change my global variable frequently and have the functions respect the change, without having to use `ClearAll` or to re-define every function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Maybe it does, but I don't understand it. I'm not sure how `HoldFirst` etc. enter into my situation.

Comment: The relevant point is that `var` is evaluated when the `Optional` default is set in the definition of `g`.  If `var` has a value when `g` is defined, then that value becomes the permanent default. If it does not, then `var` "evaluates" to the expression `var` which is used as the default. You must have defined `g` when `var = 10`.  Execute `?g` to see the definition of `g`; you should see `g["label", x_, y_ : 10] := x + y`. Then clear `var` and redefine `g`. Then `?g` should show `g["label", x_, y_ : var] := x + y`.

Comment: I don't understand the objection to `ClearAll` -- you're stuck with how *Mathematica* works. But here's an alternative: `Block[{var},
 g["label", x_, y_: var] := x + y
 ]`

Comment: Ohhh. Now I see. I thought you were suggesting to use `ClearAll` between every time I decide to change the value of `var`. In fact, I just need to use it once to clear `var`, then re-define the function so that `var` remains in the function definition, and then the function responds to changes in `var`.

Comment: Right! :) -- Best,

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6337753