# Drop row if sum of part of row is equal to zero

Tags: matrix, warning-messages, list-manipulation

My problem is the following:

Suppose I have a matrix `A` which looks the following:

```
A = {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0},
     {5, 6, 0, 0, 1}, {6, 7, 0, 0, 0}}
```

What I want *Mathematica* to do is to drop or delete an entire row if the sum of columns 3,4&5 of that specific row is equal to zero.

E.g. `A[[1]]` should be dropped because the sum of the last three elements of this row is zero. Same for the last row of matrix `A`.

I tried the following but it's not working, and I don't know whether it's my fault or whether *Mathematica* encountered a problem with that specific case:

```
A2 = Do[If[
   Transpose[A][[3]][[i]] + Transpose[A][[4]][[i]] + 
     Transpose[A][[5]][[i]] = 0, Drop[A[[n]]]], {i, 
   Length[Transpose[A][[1]]]}]
A
```

> Set::write: Tag Plus in 0+0+0 is Protected.
>
> Set::write: Tag Plus in 0+0+1 is Protected.
>
> Set::write: Tag Plus in 0+0+1 is Protected.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Set::write will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0, 0, 
>     1}, {6, 7, 0, 0, 0}}

Comment: Use `Equal` (`==`) to test for equality, not `Set` (`=`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A = {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0,0, 1}, {6, 7, 0, 0, 0}};
Select[A, Total@#[[3 ;; 5]] != 0 &]
Cases[A, _?(Total@#[[3 ;; 5]] != 0 &)]
```

> {{2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0, 0, 1}}

Comment: Also `DeleteCases[A, {x_, y_, z__ /; Total[{z}] == 0} ]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, or `DeleteCases[A, {_, _, z__ /; +z == 0}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Learnt something new, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

### Error

I addressed the cause of this error message here:

- [A combination of Set::setraw and Set::shape errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2033/121)
- [How do I identify the source of a "Tag times protected" error?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982/121)

Using `findBadSets` from the second one will return:

```
Plus     Transpose[hallo][[3]][[i]]+Transpose[hallo][[4]][[i]]+Transpose[hallo][[5]][[i]]
```

which indicates the error.

### Solutions

As to the solution to your problem here is another option:

```
Select[A, #3 + #4 + #5 != 0 & @@ # &]
```

Or assuming all positions to add are contiguous at the end of the subset:

```
Select[A, +##3 != 0 & @@ # &]
```

For better performance I suggest this variation of the `Pick` solutions:

```
Pick[A, A[[All, {3, 4, 5}]] ~Total~ {2} // Unitize, 1]
```

### Timings

Timings for all methods posted so far:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

A = a = RandomInteger[6, {500000, 5}];

Select[A, Total@#[[3 ;; 5]] != 0 &]                    // timeAvg
Cases[A, _?(Total@#[[3 ;; 5]] != 0 &)]                 // timeAvg

Pick[a, Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] != 0 & /@ a]                 // timeAvg
Pick[a, Tr@# != 0 & /@ a[[All, -3 ;;]]]                // timeAvg
DeleteCases[a, _?(Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] == 0 &)]           // timeAvg
If[Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] == 0, ## &[], #] & /@ a           // timeAvg
a /. x : {__} /; Total[x[[-3 ;;]]] == 0 :> Sequence[]  // timeAvg

Pick[A, Unitize[+##3 & @@@ A], 1]                      // timeAvg
Pick[A, +##3 != 0 & @@@ A]                             // timeAvg

Select[A, #3 + #4 + #5 != 0 & @@ # &]                  // timeAvg
Pick[A, A[[All, {3, 4, 5}]] ~Total~ {2} // Unitize, 1] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.796
> 0.889
> 0.843
> 0.421
> 0.92
> 0.921
> 1.606
> 0.328
> 0.452
> 0.733
> 0.0842
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Just another `Pick` variant (`Unitize` in case  nonzero sum !=1...test case not needed):

```
Pick[A, Unitize[Plus@##3 & @@@ A], 1]
```

Comment: Nice use of `SlotSequence`. Shorter version: `Pick[A,+##3!=0&@@@A]`

Comment: @SimonWoods thank you...like your neat shorter version...gets to heart with Boolean...no unitized, third argument

Comment: I agree Simon's code is particularly nice, but yours is somewhat faster.  However, for packed arrays at least neither is optimal -- it is better to use `Part` and `Total` to prevent unpacking.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, one is so often torn between terseness and efficiency :-) My dream is one day to find a language in which the shortest code is always the fastest...

Comment: @SimonWoods Let me know if you find it! *Mathematica* is usually pretty good there as pushing things into optimized kernel functions is typically fast.  Disappointment happens when kernel functions are not as fast as other parts of the system and I end up carting around `SparseArray[. . .]["AdjacencyLists"]` as a substitute for `Position`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0, 0,  1}, 
    {6, 7, 0, 0, 0}};

Pick[a, Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] != 0 & /@ a]
```

or

```
Pick[a, Tr@# != 0 & /@ a[[All, -3 ;;]]]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[a, _?(Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] == 0 &)]
```

or

```
If[Total[#[[-3 ;;]]] == 0, ## &[], #] & /@ a
```

or

```
a /. x : {__} /; Total[x[[-3 ;;]]] == 0 :> Sequence[]
```

all give

```
(* {{2, 3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) is typically faster than [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total), so the following variation is significantly faster than the fastest previous solution (by Mr.Wizard):

```
A = RandomInteger[6, {500000,5}];

r1 = Pick[A, A[[All, {3, 4, 5}]] ~Total~ {2} // Unitize, 1]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Pick[A, A . {0, 0, 1, 1, 1} //Unitize, 1]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.038, Null}
>
> {0.022, Null}
>
> True