# How to assign the values for the Table list?

Tags: assignment

Now, I want to assign some values for a Table list and I find that

If

```
 {mat[1], mat[2], mat[3], mat[4], mat[5]}={4,23,3,12,1};
```

it is no problem. But, if we use

```
  Table[mat[n],{n,1,5}]={4,23,3,12,1};
```

It doesn't work. Why ?  Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked several times before.  Please help me in finding an appropriate duplicate and voting to close.

Comment: Related: [(280)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121),
[(2033)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2033/121), [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121), 
[(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121),
[(24495)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24495/121),
[(24557)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24557/121),
[(40094)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40094/121)

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate the left-hand side first.

```
Evaluate[Table[mat[n], {n, 5}]] = {4, 23, 3, 12, 1}
```

Another possible way:

```
With[{values = {4, 23, 3, 12, 1}},
 Do[mat[n] = values[[n]], {n, 5}]]
```

Comment: The first method will not work the second time.  The second will, however.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the kernel to evaluate the left hand side before invoking `Set`  Try this:

```
Evaluate[Table[mat[n],{n,1,5}]]={4,23,3,12,1};
```

Comment: Be aware that this will not work the second time.

Comment: Well then, do it right the first time around  :-)